# Google Analytics: How to track transactions based on played videos

Tags: google-analytics

is there any way, how to track transactions (revenue) based on video played? We have many videos on the site and it doesn't matter for us, which video was played.

I've tried to create a goal for all videos played and then somehow combine it with revenue, but this does not seem possible.

Thank you for help.

Filip

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its not programming related may be better suited for https://webapps.stackexchange.com/ or https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can send event with Enhaned Ecomerce data that will include revenue also. The question is what will be the trigger for your video? You can send EE event when a user clicks on Play button, or when he reaches half of the video or something else